# Executing Styles based on rule Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style

I would like to execute a style based on some parameter passed through WMS Rest request. What I am trying to achieve is, while requesting the tile, I want a particular country to be filled in separate color. So I would pass "USA" in ENV parameter and the tiles for USA should be colored in different color than the rest of the world. So in the final output I would have the whole world map but only USA highlighted.

Regards
Sudheesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by creating rules in SLD . Passed CountryName as ENV parameter checking the values inside ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo. For default color i used same rule with ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo . The sample rule is as below

```
<Rule>
<Name>Selected Country</Name>
<Title>Highlight the country passed using ENV parameter</Title>
<ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>ISO_CODE</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Function name="env">
      <ogc:Literal>country</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>USA</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<PolygonSymbolizer>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#BB6464</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</PolygonSymbolizer>   </Rule>    <Rule>
<Name>Default Colour</Name>
<Title>Colour All other countries in Diffrent Colour</Title>
 <ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>ISO_CODE</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Function name="env">
      <ogc:Literal>country</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:Literal>USA</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<PolygonSymbolizer>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#67D274</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</PolygonSymbolizer>   </Rule>
```

Regards
Sudheesh

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to request the plain map as usual (so with a style that showed just the borders) and then make a second WMS request with either an OGC or CQL filter attached to filter down to just the country you wanted to show.

So something like

[image: http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/world/wms?&LAYERS=world%3Aborders&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-240.46875,-119.203625,240.46875,112.827625&WIDTH=684&HEIGHT=330]

http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/world/wms?&LAYERS=world%3Aborders&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-240.46875,-119.203625,240.46875,112.827625&WIDTH=684&HEIGHT=330

and

[image]

http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/world/wms?&LAYERS=world%3Aborders&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-240.46875,-119.203625,240.46875,112.827625&WIDTH=684&HEIGHT=330&CQL_FILTER=FIPS%3D'US'

Comment: Thanks Iant, Does that work in environment where we get tiles pf 256*256 at different zoom levels? The map control at client side would request continuous tiles based on PAN/Zoom. Basically i am not looking for a single tile of a particular area.

Comment: In that case you'd use tiles for the map of the whole world and a request for the full extent for the filtered layer. Tiling won't help with filtered layers (however you do it) as the cache will hold on to the previous answers.